# can I download iOS SDK 4.3 without Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

I am new to Apple Development Platform. I have installed Xcode 3.2 with MAC OS SDK on my Apple Computer running Snow Leopard. I need to know whether can I download and install just iOS SDK 4.3 or I have to download full Xcode 3.2 including MAC OS SDK and iOS SDK?

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg from Apple's iOS Developer's site.
2. Run the installer.
3. When presented with options to install, select JUST the SDK. Uncheck everything else.

For Delphi Firemonkey users:

1. After install is complete, you will be able to run the FireMonkey installer again (assuming you have already installed FPC).
2. When you run XCode, it will ask you to download the frameworks again. Do so.

XCode will now be able to compile and run your Delphi FireMonkey iOS projects.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the latest edition of Xcode that will run on snow leopard is 4.2, which will still be available for download in your developer portal. You are far better off with Xcode 4 then you are with 3.anything, they have made significant improvements to the entire IDE. Now getting back on topic, no Apple will not let you download new iOS SDKs for 3.2 without downloading the version of Xcode that is bundled with them.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to download just SDK.
Go for new version Xcode (4.3.2). It will take care of all your needs.

Comment: Thanx for your response. Will Xcode 4.3.2 work on Snow Leopard?

Comment: It requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later. I suggest you to download it from App store(Its Free). Coz if new version releases, U can get updates & save time in downloading the entire Application(whose size is of course in GBs).

Comment: 4.3 only runs on Lion and above, 4.2 is the last version that runs on SL

Comment: If I download the latest XCode, it will not come with all the SDK-s, so if I would like to build for an earlier IOS, I will have to get just the SDK.